# HttpUtility.HtmlDecode driving me crazy

Tags: c#, html-encode

This situation is driving me crazy!!: the following snippet does not work (as i should)

```
...
string preResult =  doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//textarea[@name='utrans']").InnerText
return HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(preResult);
...
```

The first line assigns a value (e.g.)  `"&lt;b&gt; Dummy value: &lt;/ b&gt;`    into preResult (that's expected).

BUT the next line gives AGAIN the same value!!! But it should return "<b> Dummy value: </ b>".

Debugging these lines i thought to copy and paste the value directly into HttpUtility.HtmlDecode() and guess what...it worked!!! I got the expected value!

Of course this is useless, but it proves something weird is going on...what?!!

Has anybody faced the same situation again? (dev.env. VS2008,.NET3.5SP1)

Comment: This sounds very strange. As a debugging advice, compare `preResult` with the expected value (`&lt;b&gt;...`) between your two lines in a debug window. If that doesn't help, compare it byte-by-byte.

Comment: @Heinzi: i didn't have the time to investigate deeper, so i gave up and came up with a much more elegant solution (which has nothing to do with this particular problem). But thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

The undisclosed "The first line assigns a value" step is the culprit here. Depending on what is used, the value assigned will be double-encoded.

```
// .Dump() is a helper "display" method in LinqPad .Net snippet compiler. 
// Replace with Console.Write(

var na = GetCreateXmlNode("a");

na.InnerText = "&lt;b&gt; Dummy value: &lt;/ b&gt;";

na.InnerXml.Dump();
System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(na.InnerXml).Dump();
na.InnerText.Dump();
System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(na.InnerText).Dump(); // <- Must double-Decode

na.InnerXml = "&lt;b&gt; Dummy value: &lt;/ b&gt;";

na.InnerXml.Dump();
System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(na.InnerXml).Dump(); // <- or this if you want appearance of "parity"
na.InnerText.Dump(); // <- just use this
System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(na.InnerText).Dump();
```

Output:

```
// Results of assigning pre-encoded string to .InnerText
&amp;lt;b&amp;gt; Dummy value: &amp;lt;/ b&amp;gt; // raw xml contents
&lt;b&gt; Dummy value: &lt;/ b&gt;  // double-encoding, single-decoding
&lt;b&gt; Dummy value: &lt;/ b&gt;  // double-encoding, single-decoding
<b> Dummy value: </ b> // double-encoding, double-decoding

// Results of assigning pre-encoded string to .InnerXml
&lt;b&gt; Dummy value: &lt;/ b&gt; // raw xml contents
<b> Dummy value: </ b> // single-encoding, single-decoding, but too messy.
<b> Dummy value: </ b> // single-encoding, single-decoding
<b> Dummy value: </ b> // single-encoding, double-decoding
```

When you assign with .InnerText, get with .InnerXml, then HTMLDecode, you indeed get back what you assigned - encoded string and HTMLDecode seems broken. 
In fact, you approach is broken. You HTML encode twice (once by hand, then, transparently through setter inside .InnerText) but decode only once.

If your goal is to get "same value you put in" use same methods: 
1. either HTMLEncode + .InnerXml Setter, .InnerXml getter + HTMLDecode, or 
2. Skip the HTMLEncode/Decode. Just use .InnerText setter, then getter.

.InnerText encodes only what it needs not to break the XML.

```
na.InnerText = "<b> Dummy value: </ b>";

na.InnerXml.Dump();
System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(na.InnerXml).Dump();
na.InnerText.Dump(); // <- Just use that to get Decoded string.
System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(na.InnerText).Dump();

&lt;b&gt; Dummy value: &lt;/ b&gt;  // raw xml contents
<b> Dummy value: </ b> // single-encoding, single-decoding, but too messy.
<b> Dummy value: </ b> // single-encoding, single-decoding
<b> Dummy value: </ b> // single-encoding, double-decoding
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values are stored in the XML file as `&lt;b&gt; Dummy value: &lt;/ b&gt;`  then getting the InnerText will automatically HtmlDecode the text.  There's no need to call HtmlDecode.

Comment: That's what i thought either! But i guess we 're not right! The InnerText returns exactly this string and nothing else!

Comment: I ran this with that code within an XML node, retrieved it using InnerText and did a Debug.Writeline of the text, and it showed up well formed.  Are you trying to put it on a web page?

Answer (score 0):

Use `InnerHtml` instead of `InnerText`.

This worked for me:

```
aDiv.InnerHtml = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(aString);
```

I am using this to display the formatted text on a web page.